# Multiple site.pp for the same nodes

Tags: puppet, rhel6

I need to write multiple site.pp file for the same hosts. It gives me the following error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Node 'default' is already defined at line 2; cannot redefine at line 2 on node node-002.example.com
```

For example :

My first `site.pp`

```
vi hosts-site.pp
default{
  }
 node "node-002.example.com" {
           ## Rules here to update /etc/hosts
         }
```

Next `Site.pp` with the same node but different operations .

```
 vi fstab-site.pp
default{
  }
 node "node-002.example.com" {
           ## Rules here to update /etc/fstab
         }
```

How to achieve the same.  We need to write multiple operations for the same nodes for which we need to maintain different site.pp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppet is not supposed to have multiples site.pp

If your goal is to apply manually one of your configuration, you can use the --tags option. By the way, you should configure your agent to act as [noop](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/configuration.html#noop) so it will not apply your changes when you don't want it.

So you could have a site.pp like this :

```
node "node-002.example.com" {
  class {'hosts_configuration'}
  class {'fstab_configuration'}
}
```

Where `hosts_configuration` and `fstab_configuration` are modules that configures what you want.

Then, when you want to apply hosts configuration, you could use on your node-002

```
puppet agent -t --tags=hosts_configuration
```

And it will apply the needed configuration for hosts.

If you really want to have multiples site.pp, you can do this using environments:

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/environments.html#about-environments